# CMAttitudeReferenceFrameXTrueNorthZVertical does not work

Tags: ios, core-location, augmented-reality, core-motion

I am using Core Motion to get the attitude of the device.

My problem is that using `CMAttitudeReferenceFrameXTrueNorthZVertical` makes
my Motion Manager breaking up. I use Core Location and start location updates before
starting device motion updates but my `CMDeviceMotion` object is always `nil`.

Because I thought I made a mistake I downloaded the pARk sample code ([Link to sample code](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/pARk/Introduction/Intro.html)) from Apple, where
they also use `CMAttitudeReferenceFrameXTrueNorthZVertical` and `CoreLocation` and this is also not working.

I have an iPhone4S which shouldn't be the problem, because it's the newest hardware...

If I use `CMAttitudeReferenceFrameXMagneticNorthZVertical` instead, everything works properly.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem solved.

This was because of deactivated compass calibration in the iOS 5 settings.
I think this means the location mode may not be used for getting the true north.

Because of that also **Wikitude** was not working properly...